# How to refresh the View Data Class combobox in Visual Studio 2010? (MVC 2.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I added a new model in the project, but I cannot select it in the View Data Class combobox in the Add View window. I only see the DB4O classes, which are imported from a dll file.

How do I force that menu to refresh itself?

Thank you!

Yvan

Model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace YvanSoftware_V5.Models
{
    public class Writer
    {
        public Writer()
        {
            registerDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime registerDate { get; set; }
        //the birthday is nullable:
        public DateTime? birthday { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is this model? Did you write some code or use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework? Is the model in the same project as the View you're trying to add? If it's in a separate project, have you added the reference?

Comment: Same project, models are just classes with r/w attributes, which will be stored by the DB4O persistance framework.

Comment: and you're looking for the right model? `YourAppName.YvanSoftware_V5.Models`

Comment: Yeah, but I want to select it from the drop down menu so I can autogenerate some stuff using the second combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean in the Add View dialog?

Recompiling the entire application should solve the problem.